# Laravel модель при выгрузке на фронтенд заменить id на строку с этим id

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, backend, model

Метод `getDirBySphereId` выгружает из бд все данные, где 'sphere_id' равен входящему значению. После чего все выгруженные записи должны выводиться во фронтенд. Для удобства вывода во фронтенд хочу сделать, чтоб поле id было не просто числом, а url'ом, в котором будет передаваться этот id. Пока удалось реализовать это приведенным ниже способом, но мне не нравится этот вариант, как можно сделать лучше?

```
  class Direction extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
        ];
    
        static function getDirBySphereId(int $id)
        {
            $directions=json_decode(json_encode( self::where('sphere_id', $id)->select('id', 'name')->get()));
            foreach($directions as $dir){
                $dir->id = "http://project-server/gt=".$dir->id;
            }
            return $directions;
        }
    }
```

Comment: что за костыли с decode/encode ?

Comment: Из бд записи приходят в виде объекта, с int'овым id, тип которого никак не поменять. Эта операция с json'ом сбрасывает все установки с типами и id оказывается просто полем, без какого-то установленного типа

Comment: то есть преобразовать коллекцию моделей в массив stdClass можно только перекодировав в json по вашему?

Comment: другого решения на текущий момент я не знаю

Comment: так может в справке eloquent стоит почитать, как из коллекции массив получить?

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) - преобразуют значение атрибута Eloquent при доступе к нему.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

class Direction extends Model 
{
    ...
    /**
     * @return  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
     */
    protected function id(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => "http://project-server/gt=" . $value
        );
    }

    /**
     * Или создаем новое свойство $model->link
     *
     * @return  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
     */
    protected function link(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value, $attributes) => "http://project-server/gt=" . attributes['id']
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Но конкретно в Вашем случае это идея так себе, проще создать ещё одну колонку с авто-заполнением ссылки и не плодить код